# MySQL count as top requests with limit 5

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have some table like this

**id | Name | useriD | bID | email**

In row i have something like this

```
1 | Michael | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
2 | Michael | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
3 | John    | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
4 | John    | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
5 | John    | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
6 | Jovan   | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
7 | Peter   | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
8 | Michael | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
9 | Oliver  | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
10 | Tataian | 34 | 45 | email@email.com
```

I need a query to see what name i have the most and how many times to limit them on 5 top.

I have tried something like this but i only get the first one, i need five names and how many times.

This is what i have for now

```
SELECT count(`Name`) as Requests, `Name` as Names WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to group by the name, sort by the count and limit:

```
 SELECT COUNT(`Name`) AS `Requests`, `Name` AS `Names`
 FROM `table`
 GROUP BY `Names`
 ORDER BY `Requests` DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

The result based on the above table will be something like this:

```
   Requests   |   Names
--------------------------
      3       |     John
      3       |  Michael
      1       |    Jovan
      1       |   Oliver
      1       |    Peter
```